# &Option<T> from &T

Tags: generics, rust, reference

So I have a struct with an array of keys and a method, in which I wanna do a binary search with the given key.

```
struct MyStruct<const N: usize, K: Ord> {
    keys: [Option<K>; N]
}

impl<const N: usize, K: Ord> MyStruct<N, K> {
    fn new() -> MyStruct<N, K> {
        MyStruct {
            keys: std::array::from_fn(|_| None)
        }
    }

    fn foo(&self, key: &K) {
        let key = Some(key);
        let _index = self.keys.binary_search(&key);
        // snip
    }
}
```

The `binary_search(&key)` doesn't work, because I don't have a `&Option<K>`.
Is there a way to convert the key of type `&K` to an `&Option<K>`? Or is there another way to be able to call `binary_search()` with the given key?

I don't wanna put an `&Option<T>` as type for the parameter of `foo`, since `foo(None)` wouldn't make any sense, because the `None` values inside the array are just placeholders for entries, that are semantically out of bounds.

The only solutions I see here is making `K: Ord + Default` and have `keys` defined without the `Option` wrapper as `[K; N]`, or `K: Ord + Copy`, so I be able to make `key: K` instead of `key: &K`. But it seems unnecessary to force the keys to be `Default` or `Copy`. If someone knows any other solution to this. please let me know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `key` parameter is a reference, you won't be able to move the referenced value it points to in order to place it into an option (you could eventually clone it).

A workaround would be to use [`.binary_search_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search_by) in order to express the comparison not on `Option<K>` but rather on `Option<&K>`, thanks to [`Option::as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref).
You could also find [`.binary_search_by_key()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search_by_key) easier.

```rust
    fn foo(
        &self,
        key: &K,
    ) {
        let opt_key = Some(key);
        let _index = self.keys.binary_search_by(|o| {
            o.as_ref().cmp(&opt_key)
        });
        // snip
    }

    fn foo(
        &self,
        key: &K,
    ) {
        let opt_key = Some(key);
        let _index = self.keys.binary_search_by_key(&opt_key, Option::as_ref);
        // snip
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just realized there exists a `binary_search_by` function which might work out for you:

```
struct MyStruct<const N: usize, K: Ord> {
    keys: [Option<K>; N]
}

impl<const N: usize, K: Ord + Debug> MyStruct<N, K> {
    fn new() -> MyStruct<N, K> {
        MyStruct {
            keys: std::array::from_fn(|_| None)
        }
    }

    fn update(&mut self, v: K, index: usize) {
        self.keys[index] = Some(v);
    }

    fn find(&self, key: &K) -> Result<usize, usize> {
        let key = &Some(key);
        self.keys.binary_search_by(|probe| {
            probe.as_ref().cmp(key)
        })
    }
}

let mut s: MyStruct<5, String> = MyStruct::new();
s.update("foo".to_string(), 4);
println!("{:?}", s.find(&"foo".to_string()));
```